# Prevent input from losing focus when keyboard is hidden - iOS Safari JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I have an input which has a custom dropdown section displaying results as the user types. This dropdown only shows when the input has focus so that if the user clicks away from the input, the dropdown disappears.

When the user is on a mobile iOS device, the keyboard takes up half the screen. We want the user to type (which reveals the dropdown suggestions) and then hide the keyboard so that they can scroll through the results. The problem is that when the keyboard is hidden, the focus is lost and so the dropdown disappears.

This can detect when the keyboard is closed:

```
document.addEventListener('focusout', function(e) { //Do something });
```

The problem is that this event also fires when the user clicks away from the input field. Is there some way to tell when this event comes from the keyboard hide and not any other event? I think the best way might be to implement something like:

```
function hideDropdown() {
    If keyboard was just hidden
        return
    else 
        proceed to hide dropdown
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific plugin you are using for the dropdown? Generally you can force the dropdown to stay open in most cases. And then you can create listener to the focus event in javascript which is similar to listening to the keyboard open event. Also you can use the blur listener to handle the keyboard close.

Comment: Sounds like autocomplete to me, why do you hide the custom dropdown in first place?